# how to interact c program with 3d model?

Tags: opencv, 3d

Since for a while, I have been really interested in Image processing especially in VFX. After I watched several movie such as **Rise of the Planet of the Ape**, I have been trying to replace the face of actor by 3d model without the special feature points have to marked on the face.

[image]

[image]

As you can see in the second picture, I can get the point on my face.

I wish to combine this points position with a 3d model so that I could control the model with my face expression...

What can I do? 3dMax or Maya do not have the plug in( or I am too stupid that I could not find that), unity is also a good solutions. I once tried to use openGL, and I could control the model's position, however, controlling the face expression of the model is more difficult...

Could anyone help me, give me some suggestions or some paper to read ~

Thanks a lot